# Best method to shuffle songs in music player

Tags: android, random, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to make a music player app. For the shuffle option in the app ,

let's say when one song is completed, I use the Random function to generate a number from the list of the songs' ID.

```
Random r=new Random();
int i1= r.nextInt(songs.newCurrentPlayList.size()-1);
songs.newCurrentPlayingSongItemInPlaylist=i1;
```

Using this method, many times the song is repeated. That's why I am skeptical about using this method.

Is there any better approach to shuffle the songs?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I suggest your read this: https://labs.spotify.com/2014/02/28/how-to-shuffle-songs/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the random from the total count of songs available.
Once the song played or selected you can add that number to array. Again while doing the random you can check using array, is it the same number generated by function or not.